# Is Facebook's token_for_business unique for a user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here's a good guide on how to use Facebook's Business Mapping API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

It's however unclear if a user's token_for_business is unique for that particular user. It's also unclear if the token will expire at any time.

The name itself, "token", hints that it is a value that will expire.

Insights on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is unique for one particular user. It should not expire, especially not if the user stay authorized in the Apps.

> ...a string which is the same for this person across all the apps managed by the same Business Manager

Important:

> If the owning business changes, the value of token_for_business will also change

Comment: Thanks! How can you know it's unique for one particular user?

Comment: because everything else would make no sense at all ;)